# How can I convert an AIML file to CSV file?

Tags: aiml

I am trying to make a chatbot android application. Please tell me how can I convert my .aiml file to .aiml.csv

Answer (score 2):

If you want to know the process, you may go through Google's Program-AB and understand how it processes all tags. Also, it is build in Java so you can copy these classes to your application.

https://code.google.com/archive/p/program-ab/source